# R ggplot2 set x-axis limits for categorical data using stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, axis

How do I explicitly set the scale of my x-axis after calling `ggplot2::stat_summary()` on categorical variables?

I am attempting to set the start and end value for the x-axis. I've mapped a factor variable to `x`, but I can't get `scale_x_discrete()` to work. Is this because I calculated the `mean` and `mean_sdl` with a statistics layer?

This is [my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7393Q.png). However, the following code

```
library(ggplot2)
data(barley, package = "lattice")
# Ribbon plot: depicting overlapping measures of spread
ggplot(barley, aes(x = year, y = yield, col = site, fill = site, group = site)) +

# Create mean yield as line
stat_summary(fun.y = mean,
             geom = "line",
             size = 1) +

# Show standard deviation of each site
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl,
             fun.args = list(mult = 1),
             geom = "ribbon",
             col = NA,
             alpha = 0.1) +

# Scale axes
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 70), breaks = seq(0, 70, by = 10)) +
scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1932", "1931"), breaks = c("1932", "1931")) +

# Make pretty
labs(x = "Year", y = "Yield (bushels/acre)", col = "Site", fill = "Site") +
theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
      axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(color = "black"),
      axis.line.y.left = element_line(color = "black")
)
```

generates [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBfZC.png). I want my x-axis to start at 1932 and end at 1931.

I could transform the `x` aesthetic with `as.integer(year)` and call `scale_x_continuous()`, but this seems like a lot of extra work.

**UPDATE**

Adding `expand = c(0, 0)` to the `scale_x_discrete` call fixed the issue.

Comment: Does adding `expand = c(0, 0)` to the x scale do what you want?

Comment: thanks.  For me I had to expand upwards of  1.0 `scale_x_discrete( expand = c(-1.03, 1.03) )`